# difference filter is not displaying difference of two lists as expected

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2, difference

I am creating an Ansible playbook to check databases defined in Ansible `vars` against those on the database server and delete the databases on the server that are not defined (i.e.: old test databases previously defined).

The playbook:

```yaml
vars: 
  dbs:
  - database1
  - database2

task:

- name: collect a list of all databases currently on the server
  postgresql_query:
    db: postgres
    query: "select datname from pg_database where not datistemplate and datname <> 'postgres';"
  delegate_to: database_server.fqdn
  become_user: postgres
  register: all_databases_on_server

- name: what is the difference
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ all_databases_on_server.query_result | difference(dbs) }}"
```

The below is the output (verbose mode) of the task `collect a list of all databases currently on the server`.

```json
{
   "query_all_results": [
        [
            {
                "datname": "database1"
            },
            {
                "datname": "database2"
            },
            {
                "datname": "database3"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "query_list": [
        "select datname from pg_database where not datistemplate and datname <> 'postgres';"
    ],
    "query_result": [
        {
            "datname": "database1"
        },
        {
            "datname": "database2"
        },
        {
            "datname": "database3"
        }
    ],
    "rowcount": 3,
    "statusmessage": "SELECT 3"
}
```

As `query_result` is a list, I was expecting the output of the `difference` filter to be: `database3`, instead it returns the list of all databases on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a simple list, you do have a list of dictionaries.

I.e.:

```json
{
    "datname": "database1"
}
```

Is an object or dictionary; having only one element of key `datname`.

What you can do is to create yourself a simple list, thanks to the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map).

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      all_databases_on_server.query_result | map(attribute='datname')
        | difference(dbs)
```